# Does not get exception when collection is empty with Sum method and Nhibernate

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, sum, iqueryable

I have a `IQueryable` with NHibernate and I would like to have an linq query to sum an specific column, but, when my condition on `Where` method give me an empty result I do not want to get an exception, but I would not like to hit an query to get all records and after it sum on memory, I would like something like `coalese` sql command, for sample:

```
// I get exception when its empty
var query = MyQueryable()
              .Where(x => x.IsDone)
              .Select(x => x.Value)
              .Sum();
```

I have to do something like this:

```
// I get 0, its ok, but ToList(), list all records on memory, 
// I just want to get a single value

var query = MyQueryable()
               .Where(x => x.IsDone)
               .Select(x => x.Value)
               .ToList()
               .Sum();
```

Is there any way?

Thank you.

Comment: What a about an if condition using the Any operator?

Comment: Have you tried `DefaultIfEmpty` ?

Comment: The Linq of NHibernate does not support `DefaultIfEmpty` :(

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to cast `Value` to a nullable type.

For example, assuming `Value` is an `int` property:

```
var result = MyQueryable()
                 .Where(x => x.IsDone)
                 .Select(x => (int?)x.Value)
                 .Sum()
             ?? 0;
```

Since a `Sum()` on a nullable enumerable will return null for an empty source, the coalesce operator (`??`) takes care of returning 0 when that happens.